# Gradient Descent on Hinge Loss SVM Python implmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent algorithm to minimize the objective of hinge loss of SVM. The equation I am trying to implement is 
[image: Hinge Loss]

and max function is handled by sub gradient technique as below.
[image: Differentiation of max function]

The issue is I am not able to get proper convergence. Every time I run the code, the weights w turn out to be different.

Below is python implementation

```
import sys;
import random;

## Helper function
## Dot_product : calculates dot product
## of two vectors in argument

def dot_product(a,b):
        result = [];
        for col in range(0,len(a),1):
            t = a[col]*b[col];
            result.append(t);
        return sum(result)

dataset=[];
dataset = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [50,2]]
label_dictionary ={'2': -1.0, '1': -1.0, '4': 1.0, '3': 1.0, '0': -1.0, '5': 1.0, '6': 1.0}

cols = len(dataset[0]);
rows = len(dataset);

w = []
for i in range(0, cols, 1):
    w.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
print('W = ', w)

# gradient descent
eta = 0.01;
error = 2;
iterations = 1;
difference = 1;

delf = [0]*cols;
#for i in range(iterations):

while(difference > 0.001):
    #print('Starting gradient descent.');
    for row_index in range(rows):
        if str(row_index) in label_dictionary:

            # calculate delf
            xi = dataset[row_index];
            yi = label_dictionary.get(str(row_index))

            dp = dot_product(w,xi); # w*xi
            condition = dp*yi;

            # Sub gradient. Diff of max.
            if(condition < 1):
                for col in range(cols):
                    delf[col] +=  -1*xi[col]*yi;
            elif(condition>=1):
                delf = [0]*cols;

            # Update
            for j in range(0, cols, 1):
                w[j] = w[j] - eta * delf[j];

            # Compute error
            #print('W',w);
            prev = error;
            error = 0;
            for i in range(0, rows, 1):
                dp = dot_product(w, dataset[i]);
                if str(i) in label_dictionary:
                    yi = int(label_dictionary[str(i)]);
                    error += (yi - dp) ** 2

            difference = prev - error;
            print('Error',difference)

print('W ',w)


# Predictions
# row labels that are not in
# dictionary

## Start Predictions

## if rowindex is not in labels dictionary
## that is our test sample

for index,x in enumerate(dataset):

    if(str(index) not in label_dictionary):
        #print('Testing data found', index, x)
        dp = dot_product(w,x);
        if(dp > 0):
            print(1,index);
        else:
            print(0,index);
```

Comment: One general note - this code is really not pythonic, I would suggest either implement this in language that you know well first (it seems like you are C++/Java person) or first learn good python, as you might loose lots of time tracking down bugs when you do complex things in a language that is new to you. In terms of code itself - you never reset "delf" between iterations, your gradients are accumulating and cannot converge. Side note - your "error" is square error, while SVM does not optimize it, so using it as stopping criterion seems very odd.

Comment: thanks, I agree to pythonic comment I still learning :), I ain't resetting the `delf` in the `elif`. The idea is if `max(0,condition)` so the direction `delf` should be zero at that instance. At least that's my interpretation of equation. And I didn't understand the error part. I want the convergence to stop when it is almost near to the minimal point. Could you suggest few more points please.

Comment: I am talking about your true cluase. You are doing `delf[col] += ` and you never reset it **between** iterations. You should add `delf = [0] * cols` just after `if(condition < 1):` and before your loop over cols. Or just change `+=` to `=`. The "error part" refers to the fact that "close to minimal point" is a hard to detect thing, and your definition of "closeness" will work for **linear regression** (L2 error) but has nearly no meaning for SVM and its hinge loss. You should compute difference in **hinge loss**, not in **squared loss**.